# Why is my azure webapp request sometimes slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service

My azure web application sometimes reacts very slowly. He waits a few seconds before executing the request.

- Of course I have the setting "always on" turned on.
- It's running on a S2 service plan.
- Avg users online 3
- No vertical or horizontal scaling configured.

Application

1. Asp.net MVC
2. .net Framework 4.6.1
3. C#

Does anyone have an idea why this problem occasionally occurs?

[image: Azure Appl insights -profile]

Comment: what is the pricing tier you're using on your app service plan? Is it free or basic?

Comment: I have an S2 service plan

Comment: Is it an MVC app?

Comment: Yes it's an Asp.Net MVC Application.

Comment: Is your app horizontal scaled? Maybe that's the time needed to bring up a new instance.

Comment: No there is no vertical or horizontal scaling configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i see based on your picture that there is a wait time of 98.71% and lots of wait time from the compiler, so i would recommend you to consider to use precompiled views on your mvc app, to avoid the runtime compilation of the views. If you are using Azure DevOps, you should be able to change your task to build the solution and add the following options on the MSBuild arguments.

`/p:PrecompileBeforePublish=true /p:UseMerge=true /p:SingleAssemblyName=AppCode`

Comment: Also please reference to this article to troubleshoot any other performance issues you face - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/performance-testing

Comment: And in case the number of website users increase significantly, i would recommend you to consider to perform Load Tests - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/load-test/app-service-web-app-performance-test?view=azure-devops

Comment: Omg this makes a huge differens. Let me test this for a few days. And then I will update whether it has been totally resolved

Answer (score 0):

When you see the WebApp being slow it is important to understand what HTTP requests are slow and whether those HTTP requests are slow all the time or it is an intermittent issue? How are the CPU and memory metrics and what is the pattern of slowness? If you have application Insights enabled please navigate to the "Performance" tab to see the requests were are slow and whether they are dependent on an external component.

Collecting CLR profiler in the context of slowness will reveal where the time is spent.

You can navigate to Azure Portal-->WebApp-->Diagnose and solve problem blade-->Diagnostic tools-->Autoheal and enable the rule to collect the CLR profiler traces on slowness.

Once the rule triggers it will collect the profiler traces and build a report for your review.